# How to use packages in different Python versions? (Tensorflow ARM 64 - Python3.6.9, Librosa 0.9.2 - Python3.8)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, cross-compiling, librosa

I am using a Jetson Nano with JetPack 4.6.1. After hours of solving on the TensorFlow problem, I figured out that TF-ARM64 only supports Python3.6.9, which is the default python version.
Now I require Librosa, which just dropped the official support for Python3.6 in their newest versions.

I thought about rolling back the Librosa package that can support Python3.6, but the application that I need to run does not allow that (new functions are used).

I was hoping there could be a way to run both Librosa and TensorFlow in the same application, given the situation.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The original Linux for Jetson Nano is based on Ubuntu 18.04, which I assume you are using since you mention Python 3.6 by default.

The latest [Jetson Linux](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-linux)
unfortunately, does not support Jetson Nano, which leaves things in a pretty difficult spot right now.

However, there are *unofficial* Ubuntu 20.04 images for Jetson Nano, which include Tensorflow and Python 3.8. These can be found here: [Qengineering/Jetson-Nano-Ubuntu-20-image](https://github.com/Qengineering/Jetson-Nano-Ubuntu-20-image).